# Waterline not checking the foreign key existance

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I have created a one-to-many collection across two models.

model: car
primaryKey: carId

```
carInGarrage:
  {
    model: 'garrage'
  }
```

model: garrage
primaryKey: garrageId

```
carsUnderMaint:
 {
   collection: 'car',
   via: 'carInGarrage'
 }
```

However when I attempt to create a car with a `garrageId` which doesn't exist, sails doesn't check the validity of `garrageId` and successfully creates a record in the car table with the non-existent `garrageId` in the `carInGarrage` column.

Adapter: `sails-postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `required: true` to the `garrageId` attribute of your `carInGarrage` model. So that is looks like this;

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        carrInGarrage: {
            garrageId: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See this link on [sails model validation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations)

Comment: Hi @brad, `carInGarrage` is not the model, instead it is an attribute of the model `car`. In plain English, my concern is, in a one-to-many relation sails+waterline doesn't check for the existence/validity of the foreign key and blindly accepts whatever value is provided.